# What Do These 2 Icons Mean in VS 2019 Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm creating a new MVC Core application and plagiarizing some code from another MVC App. I'm seeing differences in the folder structure and the Icons are different. I'm trying to understand what the icons tell me about the solutions.

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing the green icon on an old Webforms app of mine.